# Detect encoding text file by VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am working with VBA/excels, reading text file.
I do not know how to detect encoding of file(unicode, SHIFT-JIS)
Please guide me about this problem?

Comment: Refer to [this](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?25095-Solved-Check-the-file-encode-type) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13911580/7690982). Didn't test...

Comment: thank @danieltakeshi, I will check now